# 2d javascript array using json notation (help me clear up the confusion)

Tags: javascript

I am writing Tetris in JavaScript as practice, and i am somewhat confused by the array notation that i am using. 
Here's the array that i have that stores all my pieces.

```
var pieces = [[[1,1],
               [1,1]],

              [[1,0],
               [1,0],
               [1,1]],

              [[0,1],
               [0,1],
               [1,1]],


              [[0,1,0],
               [1,1,1]],

              [[1,0],
               [1,1],
               [0,1]],

              [[0,1],
               [1,1],
               [1,0]]];
```

What is this notation called? How is this difference from just saying "new array()"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an array literal, you create the array and supply the values in one go.

`var a = [];` is the same as `var a = new Array();`

But new Array() will give you an empty array, there is no way to supply values simultaneously the way you can with the literal syntax.

Comment: Actually you can: `new Array(1,2,3)` gives you the same as `[1,2,3]`. However there is a trap there in that `new Array(10)` is an array of ten undefineds, not an array containing one integer! IMO: stick to the array literal syntax, it is also easier to read. It didn't work in Netscape 3, but y'know I think we can live with that in this century.

Answer (score 0):

It's called JSON, Javascript Object Notation.